# Defining a function that outputs a matrix, and later finding its eigenvalues

Tags: plotting, matrix, variable-definitions, eigenvalues

I am trying to do the following:

I have a simple 2x2 matrix that depends on three parameters (physically -- momentum coordinates kx, ky, kz). Then I want to replace each of these parameters by a matrix block of size "cut x cut" (physically -- Peirels substitutaion with a cut-off). The results is a "2*cut x 2*cut" matrix. I want to study eigenvalues of this matrix.

Let me show how I implement this, step by step, in my code. The problem is that in the end I get wrong results, and I don't understand why.

First, I define the small matrix that depends on three parameters. For example (although in general I also have powers of kx,ky,kz):

```
H[kx_,ky_,kz_]:=kx*PauliMatrix[1]+ky*PauliMatrix[2]+kz*PauliMatrix[3];
```

Next, I know I will replace parameters kx, ky, kz (and potentially also their powers) by some matrix blocks. I define these blocks as follows:

```
a[cut_] := Module[ 
   {c = cut, t},
   t = ConstantArray[0, {c, c}];
   Do[t[[i, i + 1]] = Sqrt[i], {i, 1, c - 1}]; 
   t
   ];

aDag[cut_] := ConjugateTranspose[a[cut]];

eye[cut_] := IdentityMatrix[cut];
```

Now I substitute the parameters kx,ky,kz by the blocks defined above:

```
HLLz[kz_, cut_] := 
  ArrayFlatten[
   H[kx, ky, kz] /. {kx -> (a[cut] + aDag[cut])/Sqrt[2], 
     ky -> I*(a[cut] - aDag[cut])/Sqrt[2], 
     kz -> kz*IdentityMatrix[cut]}];
```

For example,

```
HLLz[kz, 6] // MatrixForm
Eigenvalues[HLLz[kz, 3]] // MatrixForm
```

correctly output

[image]

These eigenvalues can be plotted as a function of kz

```
Plot[Sort[{-kz, kz, -Sqrt[2 + kz^2], Sqrt[2 + kz^2], -Sqrt[4 + kz^2], 
   Sqrt[4 + kz^2]}, Greater], {kz, -2, 2}]
```

Leading again to a correct output

[image]

However, when I calculate the eigenvalues and plot them in one step (for example when I want to apply this calculations to more complicated models which do not have analytic solution for eigenvalues), I get something wrong. This piece of code:

```
Plot[Sort[Eigenvalues[HLLz[kz, 3]], Greater], {kz, -2, 2}]
```

outputs the following different and wrong plot of eigenvalues:

[image]

Could anybody explain to me why the two pieces of code yield different plots? How do I correct the latter piece of code where I calculate the eigenvalues and plot them in a single cell/step?

Comment: Still trying to trace down exactly where the error is, but it's due to calling `HLLz` with a numerical input: evaluate `Eigenvalues[HLLz[0.1, 3]]` and 
`Eigenvalues[HLLz[kz, 3]] /. kz -> 0.1`.

Comment: Make the following modifications: In the definition of `HLLz[kz_, cut_]`, use `HLLz[kzp_, cut_]` instead and modify `kz -> kz*IdentityMatrix[cut]` to `kz -> kzp*IdentityMatrix[cut]`. It's hard to trace out exactly what is happening, but by using the same symbol there and plugging in numbers *before* the replacement happens, the final (numerical) matrix is wrong, and so the eigenvalues are wrong.

Comment: I see. Yes this is making sense, and seems to correct the output. Thank you @march !

Comment: I'll go ahead and write an answer so that this Q&A can be completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to trace out *exactly* what is happening (for instance by using `Trace`: there is just too much there to sift through), but problem is in the definition of `HLLz` and the difference between calling it with a symbolic vs a numerical `kz`.  Note that

```
Eigenvalues[HLLz[kz, 3]] /. kz -> 0.1
(* {-0.1, 0.1, -1.41774, 1.41774, -2.0025, 2.0025} *)
```

is correct whereas

```
Eigenvalues[HLLz[0.1, 3]]
(* {-2.01133, 2.00884, 1.41814, -1.41714, 0.1, -0.0985211} *)
```

is not.  The issue is due to calling `H[kx, ky, kz]` inside the definition of `HLLz` and then making the the replacement

```
kz -> kz*IdentityMatrix[cut]
```

Since `kz` is the argument for the original function, the numerical value of `kz` gets put in *first* before the replacement is made, and so the matrix and hence the eigenvalues will be different.

To fix this in the simplest way, make the following modifications: In the definition of `HLLz[kz_, cut_]`, use `HLLz[kzp_, cut_]` instead and modify `kz -> kz*IdentityMatrix[cut]` to `kz -> kzp*IdentityMatrix[cut]`, i.e. define

```
HLLz[kzp_, cut_] := ArrayFlatten[
  H[kx, ky, kz] /. {
    kx -> (a[cut] + aDag[cut])/Sqrt[2], 
    ky -> I*(a[cut] - aDag[cut])/Sqrt[2], 
    kz -> kzp*IdentityMatrix[cut]
   }
 ];
```